# Can we use SkypeKit to take landline call

Tags: sdk, skype

Looking forward to create an application with SkypeKit.

Can we make a call to a landline using this SDK/API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this thread:

http://devforum.skype.com/t5/Conversations-Calling/Dial-phone-number-that-not-in-contact-list/td-p/5387